# Trouble with Android permissions request running code before user input

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've got the following helper methods to check permissions:

```
private boolean canAccessLocation() {
        return(hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
    }
private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
        return(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED==checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perm));
    }
```

and I have a request method to prompt the user for access to their location

```
public void requestLocationPermissions(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Log.d("permissions",
                    "Displaying contacts permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

and where I need the location permissions, I write

```
if(!canAccessLocation()){
            requestLocationPermissions();
        } else {

}
startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class));
```

The problem I'm having is that before the user is even shown the dialogue to allow or deny the permissions, the new activity is started through the intent.  So if I have code in that next activity which requires the user to have granted or denied permissions, it will crash and *then* ask the user if they want to grant permissions.  I'm having a lot of trouble getting the API 23 permissions system to work properly on this app and I could really use some help.

So my question is:  How can I block the execution of subsequent lines of code until the user makes a choice as to whether or not to deny or allow the permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to implement this callback inside your Activity which is requesting the permission(s)

```
void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults);
```

Inside that callback, just verify the requestCode is what you requested and if grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, if so do what you need to do when permission granted such as spawn a new Activity.

Also, if ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale call returns true, you should be displaying a prompt to the user with rationale for requesting a permission.  Once user presses 'Ok', then you will request permissions again.

Comment: If the **`android:noHistory`** Activity manifest attribute is **`true`** then **`onRequestPermissionsResult()`** **will not be called**.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled for hours with this, so I just want to put this out there in case it is of use to someone.

I have adapted the code from:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

In my case, the app needs to request multiple ('dangerous') permissions. I do this when the app starts, before displaying the splash screen.

P.S. I should mention that I had no luck requesting all permissions simultaneously, hence the recursion. Hopefully, it is possible and someone can figure that out. Also, I have commented out the 'Should we show an explanation' block. The below logic doesn't cater for this behaviour, but I have left it in for posterity as it came from the link above.

```
package a.dangerous.app;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class AskMultiplePermsThenSpashActivity extends Activity  {

    static final String[] _requestPermissions = {
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        this.checkPermissions(0);   //start at zero, of course
    }

    private void checkPermissions(int permissionIndex) {
        if(permissionIndex >= _requestPermissions.length) {
            //i.e. we have requested all permissions, so show the splash screen
            this.showSplash();
        }
        else {
            this.askForPermission(_requestPermissions[permissionIndex], permissionIndex);
        }
    }

    private void askForPermission(String permission, int permissionIndex) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            //  if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //} else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{permission},
                    permissionIndex //permissionIndex will become the requestCode on callback
            );
        }
        else {
            this.checkPermissions(permissionIndex+1); //check the next permission
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        //Regardless of whether the permission was granted we carry on.
        //If perms have been denied then the app must cater for it

        this.checkPermissions(requestCode+1); //check the next permission
    }

    private void showSplash() {
        //(ta da)

        //once splashed, start the main activity
        this.startMainActivity();
    }

    private void startMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(
                this,
                MainActivity.class
        );
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        this.startActivity(mainIntent);

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the posted snippet is exactly what u'r trying in your project then the solution is easy :D

```
if(!canAccessLocation()){
    requestLocationPermissions();
  } else {
//start only if permission is granted
startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class)); 
}
```